# can i run sftp and sync framework over wcf with sql server in/on azure?

Tags: frameworks, azure, synchronization

Can I run a sftp service in the cloud, and a sql server syncing with sqlexpress clients over sync framework with wcf? I have really no idea if such a thing is possible with azure? Does azure just work as a normal webservice with sql server behind or..?

Cheers

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There may be better alternatives out there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The easiest way is to accomplish the sftp portion is via a worker role where you can bind an sftp implementation to a socket endpoint.  The sync framework code may make the most sense here as well.

The wcf portion will likely be easier in a webrole.